# Visual studio not throwing exceptions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to learn exception throwing on C++
My code is basically:

```
int nums[3] = { 1, 5, 57 };
try {
    cout << nums[4] << endl;
}
catch (logic_error e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

I thought that here I would get an out_of_range exception and I could catch it, but the program runs normally, and I get this as a result:

```
-277035873
```

It's always a different negative number.
Can somebody explain to me what's happening? I couldn't find an answer online to this specific case.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.34

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the following post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

Comment: Use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) for bounds checking.